# Get TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am getting error from this code :

```
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')
 
        curl = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        curl.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=%s",(email,))
        user = curl.fetchone()
        curl.close()
 
        if len(user) > 0:
            if bcrypt.hashpw(password, user["password"].encode('utf-8')) == user["password"].encode('utf-8'):
                session['name'] = user['name']
                session['email'] = user['email']
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                flash ("Error password and email not match")
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            flash("Error user not found")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Error :

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

This error comes out when i am submit email & password which is not in mysql database, what did i do wrong ?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Answer (score 1):

`user = curl.fetchone()` will return `None` if nothing is found. `None` do not have a `len()` and `if len(user) > 0:` will fail if `user = None`.

You can solve this by checking if `user is not None`. To do this change the `if len(user) > 0:` to `if user is not None and len(user) > 0:` like this:

```
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')
 
        curl = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        curl.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=%s",(email,))
        user = curl.fetchone()
        curl.close()
 
        if user is not None and len(user) > 0:
            if bcrypt.hashpw(password, user["password"].encode('utf-8')) == user["password"].encode('utf-8'):
                session['name'] = user['name']
                session['email'] = user['email']
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                flash ("Error password and email not match")
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            flash("Error user not found")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```